# Spring Data / Hibernate: Mapping based on a derived class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I've got a pretty straight forward Java object hierarchy that I'm trying to map into my relational database using Spring Data hibernate.  Although the classes below are fake they do represent my object hierarchy pretty accurately.

```
public class Fruit {   
    // common fields to all fruits
    // getters, setters
}

public class Apple extends Fruit {
    // fields unique to apples
    // getters, setters
}

public class Orange extends Fruit {
    // fields unique to oranges
    // getters, setters
}

public class Food {
    ...
    ...
    private Fruit fruit;
    // getters, setters
}
```

**Fruit**, **Apple** and **Orange** aren't really my problem.  I can map them into their tables using the appropriate annotations: @MappedSuperclass, @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS), @Entity(...), @Column(...), etc...

My problem is with the **Food** class.  From an OOP perspective my Food class is somewhat generic for reuse and uses the base class **Fruit** as a member "fruit" instead of a derived class like Orange or Apple.

Say we have this:

```
Food myFood = new Food();
myFood.setFruit(new Apple());
```

If possible, and I'm not sure it is, I'd like to find a way to keep this design in place while using hibernate. I can't see how to tell hibernate that when it gets to "fruit" it should pull the content from the table associated with the **derived class** like **Apple.class** from myFood example above.

There are 3 tables (@Entity)s I'm working with here:

```
Food:    id | fruit_id | thing1 | thing2 | etc...
Orange:  id | thing1   | thing2 | etc...
Apple:   id | thing1   | thing2 | etc...
```

**fruit_id**@Food, not a FK because it could reference the Apple or the Orange table, holds the "id" of the row from the appropriate Orange or Apple table entry.  What would these tables even need to look like to accommodate this!?

I'm not sure how to tell hibernate to choose Apple over Orange or if it's even possible, doesn't seem so to me so I'll probably need to go another more manual route.

Thanks for any help you may have and I hope I explained clear enough what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to have three different tables for the subtypes, you should declare `Fruit` like this

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Fruit { ... }
```

Using `@MappedSuperclass` is wrong and should only be used if you want to reuse state. A mapped super class is not queryable. The rest should work out of the box.